# Match several node property values in Cypher / Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

using Cypher 2 I want to find all the nodes of a certain label (Context), which are called either "health" or "opinion".

The query that works is:

```
MATCH (c:Context) WHERE c.name="health" OR c.name="opinion" RETURN c;
```

But I'm wondering if Cypher has a syntax that I could put it into the first MATCH part, something like this:

```
MATCH (c:Context{name:"health"|name:"opinion})
```

The example above doesn't work, but I'm just showing it to let you know what I mean.

Thank you!

Comment: Use the one that works, there is no shorthand syntax for that.

Comment: Is there a particular problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @jjaderberg well yes, that was the problem :) i solved it but was just wondering if there was a more efficient way.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this @deemeetree ?

Answer (score 13):

Alternatively, you can do this:

```
MATCH (c:Context) WHERE c.name IN ['health', 'opinion'] RETURN c
```

Still not in the "MATCH" statement, but a little easier as your list of possible values grows.

Answer (score 3):

You could do

```
MATCH (c:Context {name:"health"}), (d:Context { name:"opinion"}) 
RETURN c,d
```

Comment: Yes, I know this, but I don't want to multiply instances.

Comment: Well you did ask if you could put it into the MATCH part, which I answered